# Unable to load assembly with platform setting all win32 or x86

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I'm writing a program which is using C# and C++ (C# calls C++). On the internet people say that there is a conflict with 64bit and 32bit assembly but I have set all the projects to either win32 or x86. See image below.[image: Current settings]

I also tried to set the C# application to "any cpu" but that has the same result. See image below for the error that I receive.[image: error message]

On HansPassant's recommendation I changed my C# settings to `prefer 32-bit`, this results is the same error.[image]

Does anyone know a solution to my current issue?

Comment: Your solution configuration is set to 32-bit code.  Affects your C++ project but not your C# project.  For the latter you have to force the kind of just-in-time compiler it uses at runtime.  Not "anycpu", that's going to produce a 64-bit process.  Project > Properties > Build tab, "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox.  Repeat for the Release configuration.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for your comment. I'm no longer at work for the day. I will have a check tomorrow morning and update you if this is the problem.

Comment: @HansPassant sadly this doesn't solve my current issue.

Answer (score 0):

You will first need to identify the x86 and x64 library locations:

```
x86path = (Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetAssembly(GetType()).CodeBase) + @"\x86\").Replace("file:\\", "");
x64path = (Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetAssembly(GetType()).CodeBase) + @"\x64\").Replace("file:\\", "");
```

Then to utilize the library you want and properly call it you will want to try the InteropDotNet package:  https://github.com/AndreyAkinshin/InteropDotNet

Github:  https://www.nuget.org/packages/InteropDotNet/

You may not want to use the entire package, but it has a nice feature that generates the
code to call the native library.

Comment: Do you mean the library location of the CLI wrapper? That DLL I have added to the C# project.

I'm just reading through the readme and he is using DLLimport, in my case the company wants to use CLI. And one of the dependencies in the complete project cannot work in x64, so everything needs to work in x86.